# How to loop a StringCount command with different specifications

Tags: string-manipulation

what I want to do is count how often different date combinations appear in a string,"March 2004" till "March 2017" basically. I used ToString and StringJoin to create the searchable string and then `Total[StringCount[data, "September 2015"]]`

This works but I have to type in every date manually. How do I program a loop to run over all date combinations till March 2017 and collect results?

Thank you very much, 
Benjamin

edit 1: i am not looking for combinations of dates but simply how often different dates appear in the string.

edit 2: I wrote a loop and it appears to be working!

```
dates = {"September 2004", "Oktober 2004", "November 2004","Dezember 2004", "Januar 2005", "Februar 2005", "MÃ¤rz 2005", etc.};

keywords = Table[0, {Length[dates]}];

For[i = 1, i <= Length[dates], i++,keywords[[i]] = Total[StringCount[collecteddatesAUT, dates[[i]]]]]
```

Comment: Can you give example of an input?

Comment: `DateRange` + `DateString`?

Comment: @Nasser: you mean besides the command above Total[etc.? or in terms of the data of the string?

Comment: @Kuba: I don't understand how you mean. How can I use DateRange in combination with DateString to loop StringCount over different dates?

Comment: Please provide a small example to work with.

Comment: So for example part of my string reads (although in German) "Thursday 23. February 2017Wednesday 8. February 2017Wednesday 1.
February 2017Thursday 26. January" etc. With 'Total[StringCount[data, "September 2015"]]' I was successfull in extracting the count of repeated Month/Year combinations. But I would like to put them in a table and somehow loop over several defined month/year combinations. In German.

Answer (score 1):

Just to see if we are on the right track, we evaluate

```
DateString[{2017,3},{"MonthName", " ", "Year"}]

(* March 2017 *)
```

That gives us a string, as we wanted.  We can create a list of month-year combinations (this is not exactly the list specified in the question):

```
monthyear = Flatten@Table[
    DateString[{year, month}, {"MonthName", " ", "Year"}],
    {year, 2004, 2017}, {month, 1, 12}];
```

Create some sample data:

```
data = StringJoin[{"word March 2017 word phrase ",
    "September 2014 paragraph ",
    "March 2017 end"}
];
```

And try it out:

```
StringCount[data, monthyear]

(* 3 *)
```

No need for `Total`

To get a count for each of the dates in `monthyear`, we can evaluate

```
Table[{d, StringCount[data, d]}, {d, monthyear}];
```

That will include a count of zero for dates that do not appear in `data`.  We can select only the dates with counts that are greater than zero with

```
Select[
 Table[{d, StringCount[data, d]}, {d, monthyear}],
 Last[#] > 0 &]
```

For German, we can use `monatjahr` instead of `monthyear`.  Please check the spelling

```
monatjahr = Flatten@Table[StringJoin[{m, " ", ToString[j]}],
   {j, 2004, 2017},
   {m, {"Januar", "Februar", "März", "April",
     "Mai", "Juni", "Juli", "August",
     "September", "Oktober", "November", "Dezember"}}]
```

Using the sample data format provided in the question, we can get individual counts with

```
collecteddateAUT = "Donnerstag 23. Februar 2017Mittwoch 8. Februar \
2017Mittwoch 1. Februar 2017Donnerstag 26. Januar 2016"
Select[
 Table[{d, StringCount[collecteddateAUT, d]}, {d, monatjahr}],
 Last[#] > 0 &]

(*  {{Januar 2016, 1}, {Februar 2017, 3}}  *)
```

Comment: Ah, thank you! But If I am not mistaken, then this StringCount gives the number of dates in the data that conform with the rage of dates that was defined, no? I am looking for the number of repeated dates, so for how many times March 2017 shows up in the string. Another problem I have is that my date names are German and not in English. I'm thinking of a way to work around that but so far unsucessfully.

Comment: Thats great, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

#### A note on finding the month names:

It's possible to get these months more simply using W|A:

```
In[38]:= WolframAlpha["German month names", "Result"]

Out[38]= {Entity["Word", "January"] -> "Januar", 
 Entity["Word", "February"] -> "Februar", 
 Entity["Word", "March"] -> "März", 
 Entity["Word", "April"] -> "April", Entity["Word", "May"] -> "Mai", 
 Entity["Word", "June"] -> "Juni", Entity["Word", "July"] -> "Juli", 
 Entity["Word", "August"] -> "August", 
 Entity["Word", "September"] -> "September", 
 Entity["Word", "October"] -> "Oktober", 
 Entity["Word", "November"] -> "November", 
 Entity["Word", "December"] -> "Dezember"}
```

If you want to avoid this, though, we can string from an online dict site:

```
gerDict =
  StringCases[
     Import["http://www.june29.com/IDP/files/German.txt", "Text"],
     StartOfLine ~~ eng : Except["#" | "\t"] .. ~~ "\t" ~~ 
       def : Except["\n"] .. :>
      (eng -> def)
     ] // GroupBy[First] // Map[Map[Last]];
```

And by doing some work there we can get the months in (the dict is not perfect alas) we can get a first approximation of the names:

```
In[66]:= gerDict /@ {"January", "February", "march", "April", "May", 
  "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", 
  "December"}

Out[66]= {{"Januar"}, {"februar"}, {"Marsch", "marschieren", 
  "März"}, {"April (m)"}, {"Mai"}, {"Juni"}, {"Juli"}, {"August 
(m)"}, {"September"}, {"Oktober"}, {"November (m)"}, {"Dezember"}}
```

#### Answer

If you have a simple set of known choices this is particularly easy to do. No loop is necessary.

First set up your choices:

```
months =
  {"September", "Oktober", "November", "Dezember", "Januar", 
   "Februar", "März", "April", "Mai", "Juni", "Juli", "August"};
years = ToString /@ Range[2004, 2017];

collecteddatesAUT =
  Riffle[
    Riffle[
     RandomChoice[months, 100],
     RandomChoice[years, 100]
     ],
    " "
    ] // StringJoin;
```

Then the [`StringPattern`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/StringPatterns.html) you need is just

```
pat = Alternatives @@ months ~~ " " ~~ Alternatives @@ years;
```

if you have a day in there it's still quite simple:

```
Alternatives @@ months ~~ NumberString ~~ " " ~~ Alternatives @@ years
```

Then:

```
In[21]:= StringCount[
 collecteddatesAUT,
 pat
 ]

Out[21]= 100
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That was very helpful!